# Magento re-writing wishlist controller

Tags: magento-1.9, session, wishlist

I've re-written wishlist controller `Mage_Wishlist_IndexController`'s function `_addItemToWishList()`

and on product page added a button and called this function making an ajax call.

```
<input type="button" value="Click me" onclick="addToWishlist('<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($product) ?>')"/>
```

In controller function

```
        protected function _addItemToWishList()
                {
                    $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
                    Mage::log("main()", null, 'wish.log', true);
                     if ($session->isLoggedIn()) {
                         // code snippet to add to wishlist which works fine and returns success msg
                     }
      else {
         Mage::log("inside else", null, 'wish.log', true);
         $response['message'] = "Please login to add product to wishlist";
         $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response));
        return;
       }
```

What I see is if I'm not logged in, my controller function is not being called and nothing is being printed in log. Why so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of the preDispatch check inside the original controller file. It makes sure the customer is logged in first before executing any action.

There is a way to skip the authentication by changing the $_skipAuthentication var to true but be careful when doing this as it may have side effects as some of the operations require a customer to be available.

Comment: I've copied whole  `_addItemToWishList()` function code from core controller to my controller. In main controller inside skipAuthentication() function `$this->_skipAuthentication = true;` is already true. I'm trying to return response "product added to wishlist ..." if customer is logged in or "please login to add product to wishlist..." if they aren't logged in.